Submenu with navigation inside Avada megamenu
What is the best way to create a vertical level menu to the left inside a top level menu that will show content to the right inside of a mega menu in Avada Megamenu?
Screenshot
Tried using the tabs element inside the megamenu, it worked but want simpler solution with greater flexibility
